# Acceleration: If I know distance, time, and initial velocity, what's acceleration and final velocity?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, physics, functional-equations

So I know the Initial Velocity ($V_i$), Time ($t$), and Distance ($d$).

I know that $$d = V_it + \frac{1}{2} at^2$$

If I rearrange this, would acceleration $a = \dfrac{2(d - V_it)}{t^2}$ ?

Then assume Final Velocity ($V_f$) will be $V_i + at$

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that acceleration is constant, yes, you are correct. Notice that $a$ can be negative, in which case the object in question is decelerating. Still, the equation $Vi+at=V_f$ will hold.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention it is constant acceleration. Great.